# How to solve this: Cannot start nuxt: nuxt.options.buildModules is not iterable

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm learning a nuxt project, which uses `nuxt@3.0.0-rc.3`.

the package.json is like this:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev --open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.1.2",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "prisma": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.6.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.0",
    "formidable": "^2.0.1",
    "human-time": "^0.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "untyped": "^1.4.2",
    "url-pattern": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "untyped": "=1.4.2"
  }
}
```

after I installed all the packages, I typed `npm run dev`， and I got error like this:

```bash
 ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  nuxt.options.buildModules is not iterable                                                                 12:27:07 AM

  at initNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1304:21)
  at async NuxtDevServer._load (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev2.mjs:255:5)
  at async NuxtDevServer.load (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev2.mjs:187:7)
  at async NuxtDevServer.init (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev2.mjs:182:5)
  at async Object.run (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev-child.mjs:101:5)
  at async runCommand$1 (node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.4fde776c.mjs:1648:16)
  at async runCommand$1 (node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.4fde776c.mjs:1639:11)
  at async runMain$1 (node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.4fde776c.mjs:1773:7)
```

I did run the project successfully some days ago, but why could I get this error?

How can I solve this ?